# HDF5: writing strings, structs, and vectors (oh, my)

Tags: vector, struct, hdf5

I have a struct defined as such:

```
    typedef struct {
    string mName;
    vector<int> mParts;
} AGroup;
```

I'm storing instances of this struct in a vector.  I need to write this to an HDF (v5) file.  I guess I could loop through each instance to find the longest mName, and longest mParts, create a new, non-variable length, array to hold the information, and then write that array to the file.

Is that the best way to do it?  It seems overly complex just to write some data.

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays and string introduce overhead.  But they also make sense as they reflect more accurately your data structure. You could go with a compound datatype made of a variable length C string and a variable length array of integers.

If your string and vectors all have a size close to the same upper bound, save yourself some time and trouble and use fixed length strings and arrays.

It all depends on the size of your dataset. In terms of disk space, there is a tradeoff between overhead of variable length elements and wasted space in fixed size elements that is hard to estimate without trying. If your dataset is small, do what is more convenient to you. If it is large, choose what you favor most: avoid wasted space, semantic of your data, ease of programming, etc. and optimize according to this criteria.